# Xcode 9.2 stops compiling for < 11.0 target when using named colors

Tags: ios, xcode

I know that named colors are supported from 11.0 but our project targets iOS 9.0 and we were able to successfully compile it using Xcode 9.0 / 9.1 because named colors were used only in storyboard and not in runtime.

After switching to Xcode 9.2 the project does not compile:

> named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0

Comment: Same problem here, some workaround without modify all storyboards?

Comment: No, unfortunately no further ideas found. May be write to Apple?
Currently still using XCode 9.1 - just do not know how long will it last

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
//Please right click on Storyboard
```

[image]

```
//Alt+CMD+f
```

[image]

[image]

Now ctrl+F and paste .

```
color key=(.*) name=.*
```

and now replace find source with this line

```
<color key=$1 red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
```

//MARK:- OR Paste your key in key

```
(<color key="your key")
```

build and run

Answer (score 0):

It's a newer feature so they might have stopped supporting it inside storyboard for earlier versions than iOS 11, although you can use it in code by putting iOS 11 check and it works fine.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named:"CustomColor")
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
   view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: If you are going to go this route then it is best to just create a class called "Colours" and add your UIColor properties as static variables. That way you have a single place to change the colours and you won't have to have 100's of "if #available(iOS 11.0, *)" statements all over your code

Comment: agree, it's better to have all colors at one place if we are supporting earlier versions. The answer is for someone who wants to use this feature or supporting > iOS 11.*